# People who make me feel bore/bored

Tags: past-participles

> 1. People who make me feel bore/bored
> 2. People who make me bore/bored

In both of the sentences which word can go properly "bore" or "bored" ?

Comment: These are ***not sentences*** - they're ***noun phrases***. So they can be the *subject* of any semantically credible verb, as in *"People who make me feel bored **are** undesirable"*. Or they can serve as the *object* of any credible construction, as in *"I **avoid** people who make me feel bored"*.

Comment: "People who make me bore" would mean "People who make me be boring to other people", which isn't the meaning you want at all.

Comment: There's the highly unusual reading where it means _people who create you feel bored_ but that is unlikely to be the meaning you intend of the one that is understood

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your first sentence is wrong because the noun "people" needs a verb in the plural. 
eg.People **are** always coming and going in that house.
Secondly, "bored" is the correct answer, since you need an adjective here. ( "bore" is a noun", for example: "George is a real bore" And thirdly, this is not a complete sentence.  ( it could be a good title , though!). You could say:

eg. ***People who make me feel bored don't have any place in my life.***

Comment: _bore_ is also a verb. You could change this to be _People who bore me don't have any place in my life._

Comment: You're absolutely right Eric!

Comment: "Bore" also means "to make a hole in something", as in "I bored a hole through the log to use it as a pipe".

Answer (score 0):

*To bore* - verb

*Bored* - adjective/past participle form of *to bore*

*Boredom* - noun meaning the feeling you have when you are bored or something is boring you.

*Bore* - a noun meaning something that causes or is the source of boredom.  You can't *feel a bore*, but you can *feel boredom*.  A particular *person* might *be* a bore, though, and might even *make* you bored or feel bored.

So it's *bored* in both cases.